# Why is the CW conversion attributed to a commenter?

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-wiki, revisions-list

Have a look at [the revision history on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5356050/revisions):

[image: CWification attributed to commenter]

After 5 editors edited, the post was automatically thrown into CW mode, per the usual rules. However, rather than being attributed to Community (as it has in the past), or even the last last editor, it's attributed to a user whose only involvement with the question appears to have been a single comment... a comment that was posted just over a minute *after* the CW status was granted.

This *seems* like a bug to me... Is there something I can't see?

Comment: Weird. Interested to see what the resolution to this is

Comment: It was made **into** a community wiki by the 'Helper Method'.  This is not an account.  [It appears to be an unlisted server robot.](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all&search=helper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea -- but it looks fixed now!

Comment: but the post is no longer CW